# Option to manually sign message in waves wallets?

Tags: wavesplatform

Most wallets have an option to manually sign a message to prove ownership .  I do not see the option in any waves wallet.

When I say manually sign, I mean take a piece of arbitrary text, paste it in wallet and get signature response.

Am I just not seeing it?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no such option inside the waveswallet.
You however have a call inside the node api to sign data (with your node PK)
OR you can use library's such as pywaves to get data signed.

But inside the client this isn't available.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I think it would be a good addition in future client releases.  This is common option in many coins by default including Bitcoin.